# Did I use "albeit" correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Did I use "albeit" correctly in this sentence?

> Here is the essay (which is word-for-word, albeit some segments I took out).

Comment: [**albeit**](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=albeit): Even though; although; notwithstanding: _clear albeit cold weather._ What do you think?

Comment: Not really, and your *word-for-word* is not exactly clear either. Do you perhaps mean something like this: *here is the essay, which is a word-for-word translation, except for some segments that I took out.*

Comment: @Cerb, can we use "word by word" rather than "word-for-word"? I checked on Merriam Webster, but I do not find the by-version.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: *word-for-word* is usually used in contexts where you mean *an exact rendering of words previously uttered/written*, so it wouldn't normally be used in reference to a *translation* (since it's impossible for the rendered output to be identical to the original). Thus, a *word-for-word* translation could only be understood as meaning *word-**by**-word* (each word was translated "in isolation", meaning that probably some idiomatic expressions would come out as gibberish in the new language).

Comment: @ asldkfj: It may be just a personal preference, but I expect the (somewhat dated/archaic) word *albeit* to specifically modify the "target" word. In this case, the "target" should be either *the essay*, or the description *word-for-word*. I would therefore prefer something like *"...albeit **with** some segments removed"*. That maintains a closer link between the *albeit* clause and the target modified thereby.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Agreed.

Comment: albeit is from late Middle English: from the phrase all be it 'although be it (that)' (although it is so that ...)

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work with "I took out some sections".  It would be smoother like this:

> ***"Here is the essay, word-for-word, albeit with some sections removed."***

Comment: Yes - the best replacement here is _though_, perhaps with a hint of _though admittedly_.

Comment: +1 I was just writing much the same sentiment in a comment while you were posting this answer! OP's original is clunky because it uses *albeit* in a more general way, to mean *although*. Presumably like me, you expect the *"it"* of *"albeit"* to be a clearly-identified word/concept (in this case, either *the essay*, or *word-for-word*). We both went for exactly the same rephrasing, I notice.

Comment: I think you're querying my suggested (merely to explain the functioning of _albeit_) rewrite "Here is the essay, word-for-word, though admittedly with some sections removed" , Kristina? 'Admittedly' here is a discourse marker (speech act) (or traditionally, a sentence adverb) and is short for the comment clause 'I have to admit'. It is a parenthetical, but doesn't need the commas 'I have to admit' would.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I saw your comment a couple of minutes after my answer and chuckled.  I'm glad you could articulate "what" about our unified suggestion makes it better.  I just know "how" to use "albeit". :-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, actually I was agreeing with you and myopically didn't realize you used "admittedly" with "though", my eyes skimmed right past the "admittedly". lol!

Comment: It gave me a chance to again champion 'pragmatic markers' as a better alternative class for part of the contents of the adverb dustbin. But thank you for the admission. Oh, and I've now had another thought - is 'admittedly' _ever_ used as an adverb? The AHD doesn't indicate so, and Collins classes it solely as a speech-act pragmatic marker (though it uses the term 'sentence modifier'). Most -ly form pragmatic markers also have existences as what we all agree are adverbs (verb modifiers). _Frankly, I'd speak frankly with him._

Answer (score 1):

No. *Albeit* takes a descriptive phrase: usually an adjective, adverb or prepositional phrase. You are trying to use it either with a clause (if *some sections I took out* is an inverted form of *I took out some sections*) or a noun phrase (if it means *some section [that] I took out*). Neither possibility it grammatical. Kristina Lopez has given you an example that works.

(Some people do follow *albeit* with a clause, but require the clause to begin with *that*. I wouldn't use this construction myself).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to only use albeit when  I make a statement I know to be contestable or not the full picture and want to qualify what I have said

the quality of her ideas means they deserve to be considered, albeit her limited tenure here.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posted by the user. Please include the user's concerns and then suggest things of your own.